# Can't make my script to print random numbers until I reach 5

Tags: javascript, loops, random

My task is to print out random numbers until I get 5 and then stop the loop. I tried searching around the net but couldn't really find a solution. I'm still learning the basics so sorry if this was answered, can't seem to find an answer. Here's what I tried:

```
function myFunction() {
  let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  if (x !== 5) {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = x;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "5";
  }
}
```

Comment: what's your range of numbers?

Comment: There is no loop here.

Comment: My range is from 1 to 6, as for the loop, I tried using while and for but without any success.

Comment: There is no `for` loop in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `while` if you don't want to wait between calls.

```js
function myFunction(){
    let x=Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1;
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML=x;
    if(x!==5){
      setTimeout(myFunction, 500)
    }
}
myFunction();
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I needed. Can't put it as "solved" yet, will do as soon as I can. Thanks you again!

Answer (score 1):

This is assuming you need to print 5, otherwise just use while

```
let x;
do {
  x = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6);
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = x;
} while (x !== 5)
```